# How to create png file from View

Tags: react-native

I made dynamically some View.

```js
     <View style={{
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        width: 300,
        height: 200,
        top: 0,
        left: 0 
        }}      
     />
```

How can I export this View (its dimensions and color) into png file?

Comment: take screenshot programmatically using `react-native-view-shot` library''

Comment: Yes, I know about this option, but I can not use react-native-view-shot because of low resolution of screenshot. I need to place this View into other png Image.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**

Found this library - [render-react-native-to-image](https://github.com/jaredly/render-react-native-to-image)
Seems very early stage of the project though.

Basic usage:

```js
import * as React from "react"
import { Text } from "react-native"
import * as renderer from "react-test-renderer"
import {renderToSVGString, renderToCanvas} from "render-react-native-to-image"

describe("Fixtures", () => {
  it("does some simple JSX", () => {
    const component = renderer.create(<Text>Hello</Text>).toJSON()
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
    renderToCanvas('./example.png', component)
    fs.writeFileSync('./example.svg', renderToSVGString(component))
  })
})
```

**Solution 2:**

Ended up using [react-native-view-shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot)

And solve the issue of not showing the screen shot to the user by creating
a component that will create the layout needed, then taking the screenshot and storing on the device using [react-native-cameraroll](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll). Something like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

import ViewShot from 'react-native-view-shot';
import CameraRoll from '@react-native-community/cameraroll';

class StatsImage extends Component<Props, State> {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.refs.viewShot.capture()
            .then(uri => {
                return this.savePicture(uri)
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('saved to camera roll')
            })
            .catch(err => console.log('Failed storing to camera roll', err))
    }

    async hasAndroidPermission() {
        const permission = PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

        const hasPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.check(permission);
        if (hasPermission) {
            console.log('permission stats', 'have permission');

            return true;
        }

        const status = await PermissionsAndroid.request(permission);
        console.log('permission stats', status);
        return status === 'granted';
    }

    async savePicture(uri) {
        if (Platform.OS === "android" && !(await this.hasAndroidPermission())) {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }

        return CameraRoll.save(uri, 'photo' )
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <S.ViewShotContainer ref="viewShot" options={{ format: "jpg" }}>
              // layout to be snapshotted 
            </S.ViewShotContainer>
        );
    }

const S = {};

S.ViewShotContainer = styled(ViewShot)`
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;

`;
}
```

The way I do it in the background without user seeing the layout snapshotted is having this component root container as `position: absolute` and `z-index: -1`.
So in essence you render the component behind your UI and take a snapshot then you can unmount it.

The down side of this hack are:

1. You will need to set manually the height and the width of your layout
2. I used [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#react-native) but this can be achieved without
   it too
3. In the above example hardcoded 500px on 500px size changed it to whatever suits your needs

Hope this helps anyone...

Answer (score 1):

If you have some action or situation when to take export image. (Button click of anything else) 
Take a screenshot using this [library](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot) `react-native-view-shot`

You can take screenshot specific `View` using `ref`

Comment: Yes, I know about this option, but I can not  use react-native-view-shot because of low resolution of screenshot. I need to place this View into other png Image.

Comment: looking for the exact same thing - `react-native-view-shot ` not fitting my needs as I need this to be created on a layout not displayed to the user